# Allow only VM to access Internet and not Host Machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization, windows-networking

I have Oracle VirtualBox on my laptop. 
Currently my VM and my host (the laptop) can access the Internet.
I want only the VM to be able to access the Internet;
I don't want my laptop to get any Internet access. 
What settings should I change on my Wi-Fi adaptor in Network Options to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you do this?  What would you accomplish by doing this?

Comment: If all you want to do is prevent access to web pages, then you can set the Windows host DNS server to a fake non-existent server on the local network.  Then set the guest VM to use an actual public DNS server like Google or Cloudflare.

Comment: It is common to have the host on a different VLAN than the VMs so maybe this questionis better to ask at Serverfault?

Comment: You should understand that disabling user access while leaving the host network card connected (which you must do) still leaves the host machine open to hacking.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the VM to use the network mode of NAT, so it emulates a real computer
on the network.

Once the VM is independent from the host, you may destroy the host's ability to use
the internet. Here are a couple of method I have thought of:

- Configure the host with a static IP address that is not served by the router.
  For example, if the router is serving `192.168.0.X`, set the host to use
  `192.168.1.1`.
- If you wish to disable the resolving of website names to IP address,
  set the host to use some non-existent DNS servers. This will not stop
  internet access via IP address.

Do not disable the host's network card, since the VM will be using it.